# Media-List and Text-Overflow in Bootstrap 3.3.2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently update my project from Bootstrap 3.2.x to 3.3.2 (last release) and I discover an important difference with the [Media Object](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media) element.

I want to use in the media-heading the special less mixin .text-overflow() to add the following css attribute to the title :

```
.media-heading {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

That works well (very well) in Bootstrap 3.2, you can see it in the following plnkr : [Media-List in 3.2](http://plnkr.co/edit/B7cGRbw8DxtnXgFhnmvM?p=preview)

But, since 3.3.x I can't use ellipsis and text-overflow inside header : [Media-List in 3.3.2](http://plnkr.co/edit/GAqClT8LZlSSSwduXEa0?p=preview)

You can compare the picture below : 
[image: View in Bootstrap 3.2.0]
[image: View in Boostrap 3.3.2]
So, how can I have the same behavior I describe with Bootstrap 3.2 in Bootstrap 3.3.x ? (It is very useful for mobile user for example).

**More info :**
The modification of layout in media object was introduced in 3.3.0 and an [issue was opened (and closed) about this modification](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14990) and had repercussion for many users. 
The solution was to set the size of the media object (media, media-body) to 10000px.

Comment: same problem for me. The 1000px is a dirty hack, did you fix the issue ?

Comment: No, we have to add some css to get back the behavior of the 3.2 version. You can find the issue opened in the bootstrap github project : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15958

Comment: JavaScript is by no means a great solution, but it can help you out with text-overflow. [jQuery.dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) works great, and even allows multi-line ellipsis.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `display: table-cell;` in the rule below is that is causing the issue. Overridding it should resolve the issue.

```
.media-left, .media-right, .media-body {
  display: table-cell; /* Here is the issue */
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Adding the snippet below seems to restore the functionality of 3.2, but who knows that other issues this may create with the 3.3.1 code...

```
.media-left, .media-right, .media-body {
  display: block;
}
```

Also, this doesn't work with the newest version (currently 3.3.2) because the width of `.media-body` is set at 10000px for some reason... Changing this to `width: auto` plus the change above seems to make it work on 3.3.2. But again, I have no idea what other issues this may create.

```
.media-body {
  width: 10000px;
}
```

Comment: By doing this modification, I think we "revert back" to the CSS of the version 3.2.x.
If no other solution can be found, I will open a new issue on their github... 
Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yeah, only by reverting to the properties of Bootstrap 3.2.X. Check it in my github project : https://github.com/davinkevin/Podcast-Server/blob/master/src/main/resources/static/app/less/bootstrap-adaptation.less

Comment: See this https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15795 and this https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14990 for the reasoning...

Comment: `display: block` + `width: auto` doesn't seem to fix it in Bootstrap 3.3.6. I guess we'll have to look at Bootstrap 4 to have a definitive fix.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue by adding another container inside .media-body

```
.media-body{
  width: 10000px;
  position: relative; //media body width overflow fix
}
//media body width overflow fix 
.media-body__width-fix {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Used like this:

```
<div class="media-body">
    <div class="media-body__width-fix">
      <div class="your-ellipsis-overflow-class">your too long text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach does not work if the height of the content in media-body varies.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and solved the problem by this:

```
.media-heading,
.media-body > p, 
.media-body > span {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean word-**wrap**: break-word? That solves my issue but OP asked for `text-overflow: ellipsis` which can not be achieved combined with this.

Answer (score 0):

After mdo decided [NOT](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15958#issuecomment-101924945) to fix this bug in v3* is here my work arround:

```
.media-heading, .media-body > p, .media-body > span {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Works for [92.19%](http://caniuse.com/#search=break-all) of globally used browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue in 3.3.6 with the following:

```
<div class="media-body">
   ...
   <div class="ellipsis-fix">
      <div class="ellipsis-content">
         Some long line here...
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ellipsis-fix {
    height: 1.5em; // set the line height you want here
    position: relative;
}
.ellipsis-content {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for me as I am on a deadline I had to use this hack.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

            (function($) {

                $('.media-heading').width($('.media-body').width());

            })(jQuery);

   </script>
```