# CSS: Bootstrap media: wrapping + ellipsis

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a messenger-like layout with Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6.

Right now I am having trouble with [media object](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/media-object/). It should break-word and show ellipsis, but that's not what happens.

[image]

Just `.most-recent-message` should show ellipsis.

```
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

Live: **https://jsfiddle.net/f55huf3j/**

*Ps: I found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660494/media-list-and-text-overflow-in-bootstrap-3-3-2/28660929), but the given workaround didn't work for me.*

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f55huf3j/1/ here is the thing updated. you have to target the container of the messages not the messages themselves

Comment: @N.Ivanov Thank you for your help! Unfortunately that also makes the title `<h6>` wrap, not just `.most-recent-message`, as I want – and it does not show ellipsis anywhere.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/pgxhr0pc/1/ -- just add the `overflow` property to the parent

Comment: @ovokuro It work's! Thank you! You should post as an answer so I can mark as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `overflow` property to the parent, in this case `.media-body`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/pgxhr0pc/1/)

```css
body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.conversation {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
}

.avatar {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.media-body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

h6 {
  margin-bottom: 0.15em;
}

.most-recent-message {
  color: rgba(#000, 0.5);
  font-size: 0.85em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">

  <!-- Sidebar - begin -->
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="card">

      <!-- Recent conversation - begin -->
      <a href="#" class="conversation">
        <div class="media">
          <img class="d-flex align-self-center mr-1 avatar" src="http://i.imgur.com/CEtZcrC.jpg">
          <div class="media-body">
            <h6>
              Sarah Martins Smit dfd df df dfh
            </h6>
            <div class="most-recent-message">
              We can track errors for this kind of bug
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <!-- Recent conversation - end -->

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Sidebar - end -->


  <!-- Chat - begin -->
  <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
    <div class="card">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Chat - end -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the overflow rules to the parent div which is `.media-body` and  the `.most-recent-message` div needs to be displayed as `inline`. Also you have some CSS errors like an extra close bracket. Here's what your css should be:

```
body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 1rem;

}
.media-body{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis; 

}
.conversation {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.75rem 1rem;

    &:hover {
      background: rgba(#000,0.05);
      text-decoration: none;
    }
}
.avatar {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border-radius: 4px;
 }
.media {

}
h6 {
    margin-bottom: 0.15em;
}
.most-recent-message {
  color: rgba(#000,0.5);
  font-size: 0.85em;
  display:inline;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define the width of the parent container.
https://jsfiddle.net/7x93ofzm/2/

```
.media-body {
  width: calc(100% - 54px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should only need:

```
.media-body {
    display: inline-grid;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1qmsty1/)